# SmartTarget vs Smart-Target

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There is a tag named [smart-target](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-target), however the product name is not 2 words, just one, so the tag should be named [smarttarget](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smarttarget).

Should we merge this somehow? I tried editing and renaming one of the questions tagged [smart-target](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-target) but it won't let me.

Comment: Well, it has been a week and no-one has posted any objections to your suggestion Nuno. I'm thinking it is safe to proceed with this.

Comment: Second that. I would gladly do it myself but it turns out I don't have tag management rights. Any volunteers?

Answer (score 4):

As long as there is consensus that it is the correct thing to do, adding a new tag [smarttarget](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smarttarget) and merging the old [smart-target](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-target) tag into it is pretty straightforward.